# Node.js express send non steaming and non chunked response

Tags: node.js, express, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using `Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2` to send HTTP request to to Node.js Express server.
When I receive the HTTP response in client and when I check the `stream` status of the response I get `entity.isStreaming()` I get `true` [reference](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#isStreaming()).

In the Node Express I am sending the request response as below:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/my/route', (req, res, next) => {
  let body = [];
  req.on('error', (err) => {
    // Process error
  }).on('data', (chunk) => {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', () => {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

    // populate jsonStr response 

    // Test #1
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': jsonStr.length,
    });
    res.write(jsonStr);
    res.end();

    // Test #2
    // res.send(jsonStr);

    // Test #3
    // res.status(200).json(jsonStr);

    // Test #4
    /*
    const responseMessage = `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
      Content-Type: text/html
      Content-Length: 2
       
      OK 
     
    `;
    res.socket.end(responseMessage);
    */
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am try to avoid sending response as `streaming` or `chunked`,
Can we achieve this with Node Express?

Comment: It is not clear at all what your real problem is here?  Perhaps if you explain the actual problem, we could better help.  TCP (which http runs on top of) is a stream - that's just what it is.  You can't change that.  So your response is always going to be a stream.